# Heroku builds with a older version of package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am pushing a Node app to Heroku with a package.json file with version "1.0.0", but when Heroku is installing dependencies and building, I saw it is using package.json file with version "0.3.0" from a while back.

Here is a sample of my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "repository": "https://github.com/...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf public",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server/index.js",
    "build:webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:webpack",
    "test": "karma start",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch --no-single-run"
  },
  "author": "...",
```

I tried npm cache clean but didn't work.

I used another machine to push again. This time Heroku sees a version "1.0.0" package.json BUT an **OLDER** version of it. It has packages I previously deleted, and doesn't have packages I installed after some point in time. So I was suspecting I didn't git commit the latest package.json, but I have.

Is this because I don't have a .npmrc config file? How do I set one so Heroku will correctly install dependencies in the latest version of package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that to push to heroku/master you will have to be at master of your project as well.

I was at another branch and pushing to heroku/master. That's why - My master branch has an outdated package.json.

Comment: You do *not* have to be on the same branch name, but you do need a modified push command `git push heroku localbranch:master` see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-master